The tooltip is showed borderline

I don't want to see tooltip at the border. I don't know how to solve it. Is it any good way to make border z-index?? or other way. Here's StyledTable styled-component and Tooltip component. I changed z-index at the Tooltip component. but it isn't things that i want.
const ScrollableContainer = styled.div`
  overflow-x: auto; /* 가로 스크롤 활성화 */
  max-width: 100%;
`;

const StyledTable = styled(ReactstrapTable)`
  margin-top: 2rem;
  border-radius: 5px;

  &.holiday-log-table {
    border-bottom: solid 1px lightgray;

    thead {
      th {
        font-size: 0.95rem;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        user-select: none;
        position: relative;
        padding-right: 20px;

        &:first-child,
        &:nth-child(2) {
          position: -webkit-sticky;
          position: sticky;
          top: 0;
          z-index: 11;
        }

        &:first-child {
          background-color: white;
          left: 0;
          z-index: 12;
        }

        &:nth-child(2) {
          left: 68.22px;
          z-index: 11;
        }

        &:hover {
          background-color: #f8f9fa;
        }
      }
    }
    tbody {
      td {
        font-size: 0.9rem;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;

        &:first-child,
        &:nth-child(2) {
          position: -webkit-sticky;
          position: sticky;
        }

        &:first-child {
          left: 0;
          z-index: 2;
        }

        &:nth-child(2) {
          left: 68.22px;
          z-index: 1;
        }

        &.file-check {
          width: 100px;
        }

        &:nth-child(8) {
          width: 150px; // 원하는 너비로 조정
          max-width: 150px;
          position: relative;
        }
      }

      tr:nth-child(odd) td:first-child,
      tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(2) {
        background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
      }

      tr:nth-child(even) td:first-child,
      tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(2) {
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      }
    }
  }
`;


                  

import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useMediaQuery } from "react-responsive";

const TooltipWrapper = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
`;

const TooltipContent = styled.span`
  visibility: ${(props) => (props.isVisible ? "visible" : "hidden")};
  width: max-content;
  max-width: ${(props) => props.width || "200px"};
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: ${(props) => {
    if (props.className === "vacation-date" && props.isMobile) {
      return "210%";
    }
    return "50%";
  }};
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity: ${(props) => (props.isVisible ? 1 : 0)};
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  white-space: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 1.4;
`;

const TooltipText = styled.span`
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: ${(props) => props.width || "auto"};
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
`;

const Tooltip = ({
  children,
  content,
  checkOverflow = true,
  width,
  className,
  wordlength,
}) => {
  const [isOverflowing, setIsOverflowing] = useState(false);
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
  const textRef = useRef(null);
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery({ maxWidth: 767 });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (checkOverflow) {
      const checkOverflowStatus = () => {
        if (textRef.current) {
          const isOverflow =
            textRef.current.offsetWidth < textRef.current.scrollWidth;
          setIsOverflowing(isOverflow);
        }
      };

      checkOverflowStatus();
      window.addEventListener("resize", checkOverflowStatus);
      return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", checkOverflowStatus);
    }
  }, [children, checkOverflow]);

  return (
    <TooltipWrapper
      onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovered(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovered(false)}
    >
      <TooltipText ref={textRef} width={wordlength}>
        {children}
      </TooltipText>
      {((checkOverflow && isOverflowing) || !checkOverflow) && (
        <TooltipContent
          isVisible={isHovered}
          width={width}
          isMobile={isMobile}
          className={className}
        >
          {content}
        </TooltipContent>
      )}
    </TooltipWrapper>
  );
};

export default Tooltip;


The tooltip isn't showed at the border.
